# Is it possible to integrate React.js with Apache wicket?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, wicket, wicket-7

I have a legacy web application developed by Apache Wicket, and would like to know the possibility of implementing a new feature in this app using React.js, is that doable?

I started my research about that, but i found none useful so far.

Wicket version: 7 (to be upgraded to 9)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new feature in a **new** page is totally OK! Just don't use Wicket in the new .html file.

Adding a new feature to an existing page managed by Wicket is possible but you may/will have unsync-ed state and this will cause you problems.

Comment: could you give me an example? or hints of search for? just to lead me for an actual solution

Comment: I am not sure what hints you need. Just add an ,html file that bootstraps React. You will need to read more about React.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to implement a new feature in a legacy web application developed with Apache Wicket using React.js. In addition, upgrading your Wicket version to the latest release is highly recommended, as it provides better compatibility with the latest tools and libraries.

Comment: could you give me an example? or hints of search for? just to lead me for an actual solution